# run as administrator keyboard shortcut not working outside start menu search box

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, administrator, runas

The tutorial (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html) states that using `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter` can run a program as an administrator in windows 7.

But this method only works in the start menu search box, i.e. option four in the tutorial.

I want to run most of my programs (lots of them) as an administrator, but not all of them.
But I do not want to right-click and run as administrator all the time.

How can I easily run my program as an administrator without changing privilege level?

Comment: What privilege you have?

Comment: If you want a specific program to run in administrator mode, Right click that application icon and go to properties and click advance mode here you can find Run as administrator. Tick that option and give OK. Hereafter that program will run with administrator privilege.

Comment: I know I can change privilege level for exe but I have lots of them. I do not think I am going to do that one by one.